# Virtualbox shared folder file permission

Tags: permissions, network-share, virtualbox, files

On windows host I run a debian server on virtualbox and I share a folder which is working

```
mount -t vboxsf -o rw,,dmode=777,uid=33,gid=33 share /var/www/share
```

I already done

> sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $(whoami)

now inside `/var/www/share` I have a file which needs `600 permission` but I'm not able to set up

is it possible to change file permissions on windows hosts?

Comment: As far as I'm aware permission are server define, so you won't be able to change permission of your Linux shared folder from your Windows host. Furthermore they dot not use the same file system to setup permission.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! Yes I'm afraid too. But has to be some workaround on windows host as well or am I too optimist

Comment: Winner!  I added fmode for file perms.. but your solution wins!

`mount -t vboxsf --options rw,fmode=600,dmode=770,uid=1000,gid=1000 share /mnt/share`